# Setting non-standard color and circle in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colors

The following code plots a data sameple whereby the each data point is a red circle:

```
 plt.plot(hour, residuals, 'ro') plt.plot(hour, residuals, 'ro')
```

OK. Now I'd like to to change the red, r, to grey. The color grey is denoted by '0.75' as there is not standard letter corresponding to grey, it seems. How can I set grey circles? I tried:

```
grey = '0.75'
plt.plot(hour, residuals, 'ro') plt.plot(hour, residuals, 'greyo')
```

and...

```
plt.plot(hour, residuals, 'ro') plt.plot(hour, residuals, color=grey, 'o')
```

but none of the above seems to work. Anyone know how I can set this in matplotlib?

Comment: Add to `plot` these arguments `color='grey', marker='o'` and be in touch witg this example: http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/examples/pylab_examples/line_styles.html

Comment: ...marker...that was it....did the trick anyway. Thank you!

Comment: @Serenity Can you post that as an answer?  `plot(x, y, 'o', color='grey')` should also work.